# QHttpMultiPart to QByteArray

Tags: qt5

Is there a way to convert a `QHttpMultiPart` to `QByteArray` or other similar binary data?

I found `QHttpMultiPart` very convenient to compose mail data formats but seems very dependand to `QNetworkAccessManager` framework and as as far as I searched there is no direct way to do that.

The closest that I has been is to append the `QHttpMultiPart` to a `QNetworkReply` object which is derived from `QIODevice` and then use `QIODevice::readAll()`, but `QNetworkReply` does not have public constructors.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: @jp36 No. I checked the source code of QHttpMultiPart and it's not possible because the QIODevice interfaces are private. So I have to build my own Multipart builder. :/

Comment: Thanks for the update. I found a Qt bug about this that hasn't gotten any traction. If you want to vote/watch it and maybe help move it along - https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-39396

Comment: Was your only problem that `QNetworkReply` does not have a public constructor? I believe you could have subclassed it and made the constructor public. How do you append `QHttpMultiPart` to the network reply though?

Comment: @georg-schölly It is not the only problem. Internally the QIODevice interface of QHttpMultiPart are private due PIMPL pattern. It should be useful to you to check the [source code](https://github.com/openwebos/qt/tree/master/src/network/access) of these classes, maybe you can see a workaround

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `QNetworkAccessManager`: its `createRequest()` method (which you have to implement) will receive a `QIODevice` containing all the data sent with a `POST` request; so you just have to call `post(..., multiPart)` on this fake network access manager of yours and you'll be able to read the data.

Here's a helper class I wrote:

multipart.h:

```
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QScopedPointer>

class QHttpMultiPart;

class MultipartPrivate;
class Multipart
{
public:
    Multipart();
    virtual ~Multipart();

    QByteArray toByteArray(QHttpMultiPart *multiPart);

private:
    QScopedPointer<MultipartPrivate> d_ptr;
    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(Multipart)
};
```

multipart.cpp:

```
#include "multipart.h"

#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>

class FakeReply: public QNetworkReply
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FakeReply(const QNetworkRequest &req, QNetworkAccessManager *parent):
        QNetworkReply(parent)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(req);
        QNetworkReply::open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    }
    void abort() override {}
    qint64 readData(char *, qint64) override { return 0; }
};

class MultipartPrivate: public QNetworkAccessManager
{
    Q_OBJECT

    using QNetworkAccessManager::QNetworkAccessManager;

    QNetworkReply *createRequest(Operation op, const QNetworkRequest &req,
                                 QIODevice *outgoingData) override {
        Q_UNUSED(op);
        m_data = outgoingData->readAll();
        return new FakeReply(req, this);
    }

public:
    QByteArray m_data;
};

Multipart::Multipart():
    d_ptr(new MultipartPrivate)
{
}

Multipart::~Multipart()
{
}

QByteArray Multipart::toByteArray(QHttpMultiPart *multiPart)
{
    Q_D(Multipart);

    QNetworkRequest dummy(QUrl("http://multipart.test"));
    delete d->post(dummy, multiPart);
    return d->m_data;
}

#include "multipart.moc"
```

You can also find a couple of unit tests here:
https://gitlab.com/accounts-sso/libauthentication/commit/7d84cb417f756e663dca7362457b28bc53a1096a